# How to load records with a specific id of an associated model - Rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have 3 models, `Shop` `Mall` and `Sale`. a `Mall` has_many `Shops`, a `Shop` belongs_to a `Mall` and has_many `Sales`, and a `Sale` belongs_to a `Shop`. What I would like to do is when I go to a specific mall's `show` page, I want it so that only the sales that belong to shops that belong to that specific mall appear on that page (mall show page). So I tried many different ways to do this in the show action of the mall's controller, but I keep getting this error:

> undefined method 'sales' for nil:NilClass

This is my mall controller now:

```
class MallsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_mall, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /malls/1
  # GET /malls/1.json
  def show
    @shops = @mall.shops.all
    @sales = @shop.sales.where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today).order('discount_to DESC')
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_mall
      @mall = Mall.find(params[:id])
    end
end
```

shop.rb:

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base


    has_many :categorizations
    has_many :categories, :through => :categorizations
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :malls, :through => :mall_shops
    has_many :sales, dependent: :destroy

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true


end
```

mall.rb

```
class Mall < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :mall_shops
    has_many :shops, :through => :mall_shops

    validates :name, presence: true, uniqueness: true
end
```

sale.rb:

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :shop
end
```

mall_shop.rb

```
class MallShop < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :shop
    belongs_to :mall

end
```

Comment: After re-reading through your models, I see you have `mall_shops`. What does this table look like?

Comment: The problem is you didn't defined `@shop`, so is the error.

Comment: @JustinLicata I updated the question to include mall_shop. The answer given by max solved my problem, however if you have an alternative solution feel free to share it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This just won't work:

```
  def show
    @shops = @mall.shops.all
    @sales = @shop.sales.where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today).order('discount_to DESC')
  end
```

Here you are defining `@shops` which is a group of shops and then you are calling `.sales` on an undefined `@shop` variable.

However even if you change the variable to `@shops` its not going to work since `.sales` is a method on an instance of `Shop`.

To fix this we want to use joins to load as much as possible in one sweep.

First remove the `set_mall` callback as we need a little more fine grained control over the loading for this action:

```
before_action :set_mall, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

Then in the show action you want to load mall and join the associated records in one sweep. However when loading the sales you might want to do a separate query.

```
def show
  @mall = Mall.eager_load(shops: :sales).find(params[:id])
  @sales = Sale.joins(:shop)
               .where(shop_id: @mall.shops.ids)
               .where('offer_end >= ?', Date.today)
               .order(discount_to: :desc)
end
```

The reason you would want fetch `@sales` in a separate query is that you need to do a `LEFT OUTER` join or you don't get the shops without sales in the first query and you also would need to iterate through the collection of shops to gather all the sales if you want to list them separately.

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#joining-tables

Comment: On a side note you might want to improve the naming of your models since it is very confusing. You might want to call `Shop` -> `Chain` or `Brand` and `MallShop` -> `Shop` or `Store`. Additionally you might need to handle the case where local shops may or may not participate in a sale.

Comment: This worked thanks! Some of the things in your method were not familiar to me such as eager_load and joins (im still a beginner). Just wondering why would I need to remove set_mall? It worked even though I kept it in.

Comment: You would want to remove `set_mall` to avoid the extra SQL query. It's always good from a performance standpoint to limit the amount of round trips to the database. As you have noticed it will work anyways but it is less optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have `@shop` defined that's why you are getting the `undefined method 'sales' for nil:NilClass`